# Check if scrollbar still grabbed by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to check if scrollbar is still grabbed by the user? Can I use `.scroll()` jQuery method?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  ...
  }
});
```

What I want is to scroll the `div` to the top when the user is not holding the scrollbar. So if the user holds the scrollbar to scroll down, the function to scroll to top will not executed.

Comment: No way to track behaviour of **the scrollbar exactly**. _A scroll event is sent whenever the element's scroll position changes, regardless of the cause. A mouse click or drag on the scroll bar, dragging inside the element, pressing the arrow keys, or using the mouse's scroll wheel could cause this event._ ([ref.](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/))

Comment: so i cant use scroll function?

Comment: _so i cant use scroll function?_ For your purpose, obviously no

Comment: but is it possible? :) is it possible to check that?

Comment: I am not sure if this is even possible. Nice question by the way. You cannot track the `mousedown` event out of the body, where the scrollbar resides! `:(`

Comment: _is it possible to check that?_ Directly: definitely no. Indirectly: you have to track any "other" input method which may cause scroll event (key press, mouse click / drag / wheel etc). And even in this case you can't be sure entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe it will help someone who lands here.
Try using the scrollend event which fires when the user stops scrolling (e.g., releases the scrollbar).

```
$(window).on('scrollend', function(e){
    //code to execute when the user finishes scrolling
}
```

Note: this isn't limited to the user using the scrollbar of course.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scrollend_event